# Stable sort vector alternating large and small values

Tags: c++11, stl

Given a vector of pair of int and string something like this `vector<pair<int,string>>` . I need to sort them in a different fashion.

I want first element to be largest. Second element to be smallest and so on. Also if values are same then values must be shown in order in which they appear in original list.

Like say we have something like this : N=5 and here are 5 pairs :

```
10 bcd
2  abc
30 def
2  xyz
50 mn
```

Then output array should be : [mn,abc,def,xyz,bcd]

Explanation : Firstly 50 is largest so first element is "mn" then 2 is minimum but as "abc" come above "xyz" so take "abc" first. Then again maximum is 30 so "def",then minimum is 2 with "xyz" and then remaining "bcd" at end.

How can this be done with C++11 STL ? I know its otherwise not so difficult

Comment: `std::stable_sort` can be fashioned to do what you need.

Comment: @AndyG Can you please explain how ?

Comment: When you say ``"abc" come above "xyz"'', what do you mean?   Are you referring to "abc" initially being ordered before ""xyz" in the array, or that "abc" compares as lexicographically less than "xyz"?    In any event, since you claim it's otherwise "not so difficult", it would be a good idea to illustrate in (non-STL) code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an idea:

- Stable sort your vector of elements based on their integers
- Create a number of buckets for each unique value

  - Each bucket is stable-sorted for those values in original vector
- Print out the buckets alternating elements from the largest-valued bucket and the smallest-valued bucket
- Print the entire contents of a bucket before moving onto the next bucket.

So with your original list:

> 10 bcd 
> 2  abc 
> 30 def 
> 2  xyz 
> 50 mn

After stable sorting:

> 2  abc 
> 2  xyz 
> 10 bcd 
> 30 def 
> 50 mn

Create buckets:

> 2: (2, abc), (2,xyz)
> 10: (10, bcd)
> 30: (30, def)
> 50: (50, mn)

Print first element of bucket 50:

> 50, mn

Print first element of bucket 2:

> 2, abc

Print next element of bucket 50... doesn't exist, move onto next smallest bucket, 30.
Print next element of bucket 30:

> 30, def

Print next element of bucket 2:

> 2, xyz

No more elements in bucket 30, so move on to bucket 10:

> 10, bcd

No more elements in bucket 2, so move on to bucket 10. We have already reached bucket 10 from the other side, so stop here.

My implementation uses `std::stable_sort` and `std::map`, and doesn't completely follow this logic, but it works even in cases where all elements are the same:

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/rY9rMk)

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;


void PrintPair(const std::pair<int, std::string>& thePair)
{
    std::cout << thePair.first << ", " << thePair.second << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    // create our vector
    std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>> myVector{
        std::make_pair(10,"bcd"),
        std::make_pair(2, "abc"),
        std::make_pair(30, "def"),
        std::make_pair(2, "xyz"),
        std::make_pair(50, "mn")
    };
    
    
    // print vector before sorting
    std::cout << "vector before sorting:\n";
    for (auto&& nextPair : myVector)
    {
        std::cout << nextPair.first << ", " << nextPair.second << std::endl;
    }
    
    // sort it on the ints in the pairs
    std::stable_sort(std::begin(myVector),std::end(myVector), [](const std::pair<int,std::string>& lhs, const std::pair<int,std::string>& rhs){return lhs.first < rhs.first;});
    
    // print vector after sorting
    std::cout << "\nvector after sorting\n";
    for (auto&& nextPair : myVector)
    {
        std::cout << nextPair.first << ", " << nextPair.second << std::endl;
    }
    
    std::map<int, decltype(myVector)> myBuckets;
    for (auto&& nextElement : myVector)
    {
        if (myBuckets.find(nextElement.first) == myBuckets.end())
            myBuckets[nextElement.first] = decltype(myVector){nextElement};
        else
            myBuckets[nextElement.first].emplace_back(nextElement);
    }
    
    //needs at least a 2 element vector to work
    cout << "\nFinal output:\n";
    // create buckets for each value, internally each bucket is stable sorted
    // the buckets are sorted on map value
    // print out each element in a bucket before moving onto the next bucket
    auto bucketsBegin = myBuckets.begin();
    auto bucketsEnd = myBuckets.end();
    --bucketsEnd;
    auto nextEndElement = bucketsEnd->second.begin();
    auto nextBeginElement = bucketsBegin->second.begin();
    while(bucketsBegin != myBuckets.end() && bucketsBegin != bucketsEnd)
    {
        if (bucketsEnd != bucketsBegin)
        {
            PrintPair(*nextEndElement);
            ++nextEndElement;
            if (nextEndElement == bucketsEnd->second.end())
            {
                bucketsEnd--;
                nextEndElement = bucketsEnd->second.begin();
            }
        }
        PrintPair(*nextBeginElement);
        ++nextBeginElement;
        if (nextBeginElement == bucketsBegin->second.end())
        {
            bucketsBegin++;
            if (bucketsBegin != myBuckets.end())
                nextBeginElement = bucketsBegin->second.begin();
        }
    }
     //print remainder
     while(nextBeginElement != bucketsBegin->second.end())
     {
        PrintPair(*nextBeginElement);
        ++nextBeginElement;
     }
    

    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> vector before sorting:
> 10, bcd
> 2, abc
> 30, def
> 2, xyz
> 50, mn
>
> vector after sorting
> 2, abc
> 2, xyz
> 10, bcd
> 30, def
> 50, mn
>
> Final output:
> 50, mn
> 2, abc
> 30, def
> 2, xyz
> 10, bcd

And when nearly all the the elements in the vector have the same value:

> vector before sorting:
> 1, bcd
> 1, abc
> 1, def
> 1, xyz
> 2, mn
>
> vector after sorting
> 1, bcd
> 1, abc
> 1, def
> 1, xyz
> 2, mn
>
> Final output:
> 2, mn
> 1, bcd
> 1, abc
> 1, def
> 1, xyz

Comment: I think you need to reverse before the interleave though (or just interleave with the end first) - the OPs question has "mn" first.

Comment: @AndyG Also if all values are same then your program produces wrong results

Comment: @AndyG let each of pair has int value 1 then your program produces abc,xyz,bcd,mn,def. that's wrong

Comment: @sfjac: That was the point. I wanted OP to figure that part out :-)

Comment: @user3840069: Okay, I totally reworked the idea using stable sort and the idea of buckets to contain stably-sorted equivalent ranges.